# Can I detect when the browser is manually closed in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, events

The title says it all. I want to listen for a window closed event on my browser in WebDriver 4.8.1. I tried looking into [`WebDriverListener`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverListener.html), but I am not having any luck. Here is my MCVE:

```
public class Test implements WebDriverListener {

    private Object lock = new Object();

    public Test() throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException {
        WebDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver();
        EventFiringDecorator<WebDriver> decorator = new EventFiringDecorator<WebDriver>(this);
        WebDriver driver = decorator.decorate(chrome);

        driver.navigate().to(new URL("https://www.google.com/"));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.wait();
        }
    }

    public void beforeAnyWindowCall(Window window, Method method, Object[] args) {
        // Prints: maximize null
        System.out.println(method.getName() + " " + Arrays.toString(args));
    }

    public void beforeClose(WebDriver driver) {
        // Never is called
        System.out.println("Closing");
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException {
        new Test();
        // Never is called
        System.out.println("Closed");
    }

}
```

In Swing, we have [`WindowListener#windowClosed(WindowEvent)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosed-java.awt.event.WindowEvent-), which is fired when a window is closed. Can a similar thing be accomplished in Selenium WebDriver? To clarify, I am not looking to know when the `WebDriver` is closed, but rather when the *window* is (manually) closed. Also, I am not looking for a method which I call to determine *if* the window is closed. I want an event to fire *when* the is closed.

I looked at the following questions but could not find a working answer:

1. [How can I have Selenium ChromeDriver exit properly upon manually closing the window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735044/how-can-i-have-selenium-chromedriver-exit-properly-upon-manually-closing-the-win)
2. [Get browser closing event in selenium web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048777/get-browser-closing-event-in-selenium-web-browser)
3. [How to determine when the browser is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29491334/how-to-determine-when-the-browser-is-closed)

Comment: Are you closing the window manually? Try to add a close() to the end (and sleep for a bit instead of lock).

Comment: @cwittah yes, I am closing it manually. Using `WebDriver#close` *does* notify the event listener, but I'm looking to be notified when the browser is manually closed. I will update my question to be more clear.

Comment: Have you tried catching the exception? An exception should be thrown when closing the window manually. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048777/get-browser-closing-event-in-selenium-web-browser

Comment: @cwittah That answer really isn't very good. It's catching ALL exceptions, not just the one caused when a window is closed. ElementNotFoundException? Fire up a new browser. TimeoutException? Fire up a new browser. You get the idea...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method like below , when a browser is killed unexpectedly then UnreachableBrowserException exception is thrown

```
public boolean isBrowserClosed(WebDriver driver)
{
    boolean isClosed = false;
    try {
        driver.getTitle();
    } catch(UnreachableBrowserException e) {
        isClosed = true;
    }

    return isClosed;
}
```

Comment: This is not the solution I need, but I am still upvoting because it may be useful to others and it does not call `Driver#close`.

Answer (score -1):

Using try-catch, something like below:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        
try {
       System.out.println("Browser is open : " + driver.getWindowHandle());
    }  catch(Exception e) {
       System.out.println("Browser is closed");
    }
Thread.sleep(5000);
// closed the browser manually at this stage

try {
       System.out.println("Browser is open :" + driver.getWindowHandle());
    }  catch(Exception e) {
       System.out.println("Browser is closed");
    }
```

Console output:

```
Browser is open : CDwindow-540829C626B281B2E3F66CA5F7E169D4
Browser is closed
```

Comment: `catch(Exception e)` Catching all exceptions is almost always a really bad idea because it hides every exception thrown and makes debugging much more difficult. Instead, catch only the exception(s) you need to.